# How to register iOS device for receiving push notification?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I want to register iOS device to APNs. I know two methods

1. Sending device token to our own provider
2. Using Push Tester application**
   But I am not comfortable to use both of this methods.

**Problem while using first method:**

Our Api request requires the parameters which i won't be able to provide in my own project

**Problem while using second method:**

They ask to provide key, **.p8 file** and all those details.
I can't give any of these confidential information to unknown application.

Now my question is, is there any way to send only device token to APNs directly or any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can visit this links:

https://pushtry.com/

https://github.com/noodlewerk/NWPusher

http://pushmebaby.herokuapp.com/

and also use mac tool like:

apns-tool

Answer (score 1):

To test your push notifications are working fine or not.

https://www.apnstester.com
You can visit this website and enter the details, here you get a notification on your device if your push notifications are working. Using this will not share any of the details with anyone. So it’s safe here to test notifications on your live app.

Second Method: To register your live app on Push notifications
You need to create a .pem file and share it with the backend to implement push notifications in your live app.